# How to Post csv file in simple Html into Django api?

Tags: django

I tried post FormData using "angular Js" and then using Directly post html to django api But It Will be failure , Anyone Tried it and Known It Please Tell me your answer it is the full code i tried out :

**html:**

```
     <form action="http://localhost:55555/collaboratoradmin/test/upload_driver"     method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" id="file" name="csv_file" accept=".csv"
                      onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getFileDetails(this)" />

                <button type="submit"   ng-click="uploadFiles()">upload</button>
```

**Angular Js:**

```
$scope.getFileDetails = function (e) {

    $scope.files = [];
    $scope.$apply(function () {


        var file = e.files[0];
         filename = '';
        if ('name' in file)
            filename = file.name;
        else
            filename = file.fileName;




    });
};


$scope.uploadFiles = function () {

    //FILL FormData WITH FILE DETAILS.


    // ADD LISTENERS.
    var objXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    objXhr.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
    objXhr.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);

    // SEND FILE DETAILS TO THE API.
    objXhr.open('POST', endpoint + '/collaboratoradmin/test/upload_driver', true);
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("filename", filename);
    fd.append("csv_file", file);
    objXhr.send(fd);

}

// UPDATE PROGRESS BAR.
function updateProgress(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        document.getElementById('pro').setAttribute('value', e.loaded);
        document.getElementById('pro').setAttribute('max', e.total);
    }
}

// CONFIRMATION.
function transferComplete(e) {
    alert("Files uploaded successfully.");
}
```

**Django api:**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def upload_driver(request):
 if request.POST and request.FILES:
    csvfile = request.FILES['csv_file']
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(codecs.EncodedFile(csvfile, "utf-8").read(1024))
    csvfile.open()
    reader = csv.reader(codecs.EncodedFile(csvfile, "utf-8"), delimiter=',', dialect=dialect)

        # Redirect to the document list after POST
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myproject.myapp.views.list'))

 print(list1)
```

Comment: IMHO [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473572/django-rest-framework-file-upload) should be of some help. Also, you can improve you question by specifying exactly the error and adding your angular code.

Comment: Hi Bro, I need to post csv file in html to django, Is it clear right now!

Comment: err message: You can't access data stream after request

Comment: If I understand correctly, your angular code is doing the processing to REST, which is taken over by django on the server. So, adding the `uploadfiles()`code might be of some use.

Comment: any doubt about this? ... pls add your comment

Comment: Hmm. Try to use `request.data` and parsers as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353846/django-rest-framework-causes-rawpostdataexception-you-cannot-access-body)

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't take the any data , if u know the clear answer , post your answer